# fonts.googleapis.com called before every heading - is this normal?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm seeing this behaviour in one of the websites I manage:

```
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abril%20Fatface:regular" rel="stylesheet" property="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" /><h1 style="color: #ffffff;text-align: center" class="vc_custom_heading home-title">Some title</h1>
```

As such, on a page with one H1 and five H2, I am seeing six calls for `//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abril%20Fatface:regular`

The website is based on Wordpress and this behaviour is most likely dictated by the WPBakery plugin.

The question, however, is not a Wordpress or plugin support question, as my interest lies in whether such behaviour is normal in general (but perhaps not a best practice) or it's something that I *must* address to optimise the page.

Comment: Sorry but the problem that you have is code related and therefore off-topic on Pro Webmasters.

Comment: Seek support from the developer of the plugin or a better solution would be to learn how to [enqueue your own styles](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) so that they get added to `<head>` so that you do need to bloat your WordPress with endless plugins, or you could even use Google Tag Manager, that way all scripts and styles are handled by Google.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. However, I'm not interested in learning to develop WP themes or WP plugins, but to understand whether this behaviour is something that's unorthodox / negative in terms of SEO and, thus, needs to be addressed.